# How to edit git rebase content then save it by shell?

Tags: git

Most of the time, I have to use `git rebase -i HEAD~<n>` to merge many commits to be one commit, then I have to manual edit many `pick` to `squash`,
it seems like too unintelligent，so I tried to use `git rebase -i HEAD~<n> | dosomething`, but this way not work for my expect...

Comment: Use the search and replace feature of your editor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run git rebase --interactive in non-interactive manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394166/how-do-i-run-git-rebase-interactive-in-non-interactive-manner)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If I understand your question correctly : you want to edit the "rebase sequence" with a script, rather than an editor. Can you confirm that the question I linked as duplicate answers your need ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52007605/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+squash+many+commits

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD~<n>; git add -A; git commit --amend --no-edit`

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using rebase just to squash some commits, you can do that with git-reset and git-commit:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~<n>
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

You don’t need to `git add` because reset’s `--soft` stages reset changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you *always* want to squash your current commit into the previous, you can use [`git commit --amend`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---amend). If you want to use the previous commit's message, just append the [`--no-edit` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---no-edit).

If you only want *some* commits to be squashed into a previous one, there's the [`--fixup` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---fixupltcommitgt) for commits. For every commit that you want squashed in, you'd make the commit as normal, but with that flag, like so

```sh
git commit --fixup PREV_COMMIT
```

This will automatically prefix your commit message with a `fixup!` string. Then, when you you're done and want to clean up, you can [`git rebase --interactive --autosquash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autosquash) and it will have the `FIXUP`s already filled in for you.